# Bound and Unbound methode Error Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, qtableview, qtgui

Hello Guys i try hard to fix this problem please can some one help me really i need it

when i try to print a return value from function doesn't work i get this error

```
<unbound method Ui_MainWindow.fn_get_cell_Value>
```

here is my code

```
def handleHeade`rMenu(self,pos):
    menu = QMenu()
    quitAction = menu.addAction("Update")
    action = menu.exec_(self.tableView.mapToGlobal(pos))
    if action == quitAction:
       dd = Ui_MainWindow
       print dd.fn_get_cell_Value

def fn_get_cell_Value(self,qmodelindex):
    i = qmodelindex.row()
    j = qmodelindex.column()
    valeur = qmodelindex.sibling(i, j).data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole).toString()
    return valeur
```

i want to print the return value when i click update from Qmenu

thank you so much

Comment: If you got an error traceback, include more or all of it in your answer.

Comment: i got only this error ``<unbound method Ui_MainWindow.fn_get_cell_Value>
`

Comment: i got only this error `<unbound method Ui_MainWindow.fn_get_cell_Value>
` when i try to get value from qtableview and  manipulate . how can i fix that or i want to get value from qtableview and manipulate

Comment: You are printing a reference to a class method rather than calling the method of an instance of the class. What did you expect to happen? Because it looks to be doing exactly what I expect that code to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<unbound method Ui_MainWindow.fn_get_cell_Value>` is *not* an error message.  It is the expected output from this print statement

```
   print dd.fn_get_cell_Value
```

You need to call the method with (), but I cannot tell what arguments might be needed for the call.  Consider the following.

```
>>> class C:
    def meth(self): return 55

>>> print C.meth
<unbound method C.meth>
>>> print C().meth
<bound method C.meth of <__main__.C instance at 0x0000000003FAD448>>
>>> print C().meth()
55
```